# What is this construction of this?

Tags: grammar

You can never be in this forest but some evil power will overpower your senses.

I found this but it doesn't make much sense grammatically.
How can I dissect this?

Answer (score 1):

I am not surprised this use of *but* confuses you; it is pretty rare today with full clauses, and I suspect it is used here to give an archaic or 'fairy-tale' air to the story.

You have probably encountered  *but* joining two NPs, of which the first is negative and the second positive; here *but* has the approximate sense “except”:

> We have [<sub>NP-</sub> no choice] but [<sub>NP+</sub> compliance]. = *We cannot do anything except comply*.

The construction at hand is similar. Here *but* joins two clauses of which the first contains a negation, and acts as a subordinating conjunction with the approximate sense *without*. “Negative A but B” may be paraphrased as “No A without B” or “Whenever A always B”. For instance, Hamlet's statement “There is nothing either good or bad, but thinking makes it so” may be represented as

> [<sub>Negative</sub> No-] [<sub>A</sub> thing is good or bad] but [<sub>B</sub> thinking makes it so]

which may be paraphrased (with appropriate adjustments) as

> **No** [<sub>A</sub> thing is good or bad] **without** [<sub>B</sub> thinking making it so]
>   or
>   **Whenever** [<sub>A</sub> a thing is good or bad]  [<sub>B</sub> thinking **has always made** it so].

Your sentence, then, may be paraphrased

> You can never be in this forest without some evil power overpowering your senses. *or*
>   Whenever you are in this forest some evil power will always overpower your senses.